# Nonlinear Regression with Correlated Error

Tags: regression, correlation, autocorrelation, nonlinear-regression

Assume I have two data sets:

1. Experimentally measured data y for known values $x$. Assume the nature of the error in $y$ is random only and $\sigma_y$ is known/estimated.
2. Simulated (deterministic) data y for known values $x$. Assume the nature of the error in $y$ is systematic only and it ether has:
   a) constant offset value for error,
   b) constant multiplier value for error,
   c) combination of (a) and (b). (I think this implies the error is correlated?)

Now, I want to take both sets of data and come up with a best fit for $y$ = $f$($x$, $\beta$), where $f$ is non-linear, and I have a set of beta coefficients to be fit. I am looking for a general framework to handle such regression problems (where some data is random error only, some data is systematic error only and is correlated to itself).